# UI Collapsible items in Elm: a css-only solution vs storing more data in the model

Tags: user-interface, state, elm, expand

For example when implementing these collapsible items:

[image: collapsible items example]

First approach that comes to my mind is to store a variable in the model `expandedItems: List ItemId`

- to verify if an item is expanded you check if its id is in the list
- to expand an item you add its id to the list
- to collapse an item you remove its id from the list

There also are css-only solutions like this one https://jsfiddle.net/5hcwzf7s/2/

What would the advantages / disadvantages of css-only over the id list be?

Comment: Who are these people telling you not to store UI state in the UI state (Model)? Do you have a source? What would be the alternative?

Comment: Friends in private conversations. They have more experience than me and know more about Elm. But I wasn't sure about their reluctance to storing this information in the model. So I decided to ask this question, maybe I am missing something or I'm biased. To me it seems like the best way to do it. The only alternative I know is the css-only solution I presented in my self-answer below.

Comment: You might just have misinterpreted them, but either way this seems like it ought to be a private conversation, not something that's all that relevant to or addressable by anyone else.

Comment: Is there any other way I could have phrased the question to make it more useful and relevant to other people? Does the self-answer provide any useful information? I know it started as a private conversation, but the topic is "a css solution vs storing more data in the model", couldn't this be considered as something relevant to other people?

Comment: I don't think the problem is all that relevant, seeing as there's no real alternative being presented. The question to me seems similar to asking whether you should use a hammer or a rock to nail two boards together. It's not a question most people would ask on their own because the answer seems quite obvious despite both alternatives being technically possible. The only reason you're asking it seems to be because of external influences that very few other people will have, I think.

Comment: It's been 1 year since I asked this, and to be honest I don't even understand anymore how the css solution works. It seems exactly as @glennsl described it above, using a rock instead of a hammer. Anyone with a bit of common sense would impement it the regular way. But people sometimes like to pretend they are smarter by doing things in unconventional ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to put this all in your model. The css approach is perhaps a nice trick, but is not very scalable.

In particular you would end up putting state in the css file, and part of it even twice. Keep it all in your model, put the full content into the screen, and then just attach a class when contracted, which sets a max height and truncates the rest with elipsis

Answer (score 1):

I think storing the list in the model is common, easy to understand, and the usual way to do things like these.

I find a few downsides to the css solution:

- is hard to read and understand
- is fragile and hard to maintain
- might not work on all browsers
- uses `href` which makes the item id show up in the url when you click to expand
- treats expanding as a url change, and when the user clicks back it unexpands the item instead of navigating to the previous page
- only allows one item to be expanded at a time

On the other hand, I find no downsides to the `expandedItems` list approach. Performance might be a concern because we're operating on a list, but the user will have to be expanding thousands of items to make the list long enough to notice any difference. I don't think is polluting the model either, this kind of information is what the model should hold.